# Error in python implementation of Dijkshtra's algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, stack-overflow, dijkstra

```
def Dijkshtra(self, root):

    if self.flag == 0:
        # NOTE Run this Function only once
        self.initialize(root)
    self.flag = 1

    while len(self.visited) != 0:
        for neighbour in self.graph[root]:
            self.parent[neighbour] = root
            if self.shortestDist[neighbour] > self.shortestDist[self.parent[neighbour]] + self.weight[neighbour, self.parent[neighbour]]:
                self.shortestDist[neighbour] = self.shortestDist[self.parent[neighbour]] + self.weight[neighbour, self.parent[neighbour]]
                self.parent[neighbour] = root

        # NOTE Sort Shortest Distance dictionary 
        self.shortestDist = {k: v for k, v in sorted(self.shortestDist.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}


        for key in self.shortestDist.keys():
            if self.shortestDist[key] != float('inf'):
                self.visited.add(key)

        # NOTE Since we've calculated the DIRECT shorted distance
        #      of all it's neighbour from the parent Node
        print(self.shortestDist)
        
        # NOTE STOP Recursion, once we've processed all Nodes in the Graph
        root = self.visited.pop()
```

I've taken the help of **namedtuple** to store the weight of each node
Also Initialized the **shortestDist** a **defaultdict** to store the shortest distance of each node, which updates as traverse the graph.
Stackoverflow is caused because of the following for loop

```
for key in self.shortestDist.keys():
    if self.shortestDist[key] != float('inf'):
        self.visited.add(key)
```

Comment: Post the entire final version of your code and the error traceback in detail.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that could cause a stack overflow. The only user-defined function that is called is `initialise` and there is no deeper function call, let alone that there would be recursion... Check the exception trace you get, where you can see the stack of calls that are made, and where there is a cycle in those calls.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/arppJZ You can follow this link for the entire code

Comment: Your algorithm doesn't resemble Dijkstra's algorithm. It lacks the concept of a queue. You seem to mix up the concept of the "visited" set with that queue. You need both. Your algorithm is running in circles, visiting nodes that you have already visited previously. It should finish within one second. Why don't you implement it like it is available on so many places on the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is running in circles: it visits nodes more than once. That is possible because you *remove* visited nodes from the `visited` set, which means they can be visited *again*. This is wrong.

The main ingredient that is missing from your algorithm, is a priority queue. Also, it lacks the categorisation of nodes into three categories (visited, unvisited, on the frontier), and only provides two (visited or not).

The outline of the algorithm on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Algorithm) explains the use of this priority queue in the last step of each iteration:

> 6. Otherwise, select the unvisited node that is marked with the smallest tentative distance, set it as the new "current node", and go back to step 3.

There is currently no mechanism in your code that selects the visited node with *smallest* distance. Instead it picks an *arbitrary* node from `visited` (as in Python a `set` is unordered), and worse, it *removes* it from `visited`.

To correct your code, please consult the pseudo code that is available on that same Wikipedia page, and I would advise to go for the variant [with priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Using_a_priority_queue).

In Python you can use `heapq` for performing the actions on the priority queue (`heappush`, `heappop`).

Comment: TYSM, I followed the link and found the algorithm very helpful. I don't know what I was doing.